# Formal methods - Map of price relating cars to price with two sets BL and Fiat

Tags: maps, range, formal-languages, formal-methods, vdm++

I have a question from Chapter 5 in Practical Formal Methods with VDM by Derek Andrews and Darrel INCE which I was unsure how to answer, so here it is, thanks for any help!

If the map *price* relates cars to their price, the set *BL* contains the cars made by British Leyland and *Fiat* the cars made by Fiat. Write down the following descriptions using the map facilities and set facilities described in this chapter and chapter on sets.

**(d) The number of Fiat cars that have a price between £6000 and £7000**

This is what I think so far...

1.Get prices of all fiats i.e. **price(fiat)** returning a subset of the price map

i.e. **{punto -→ 5500, panda -→ 6600}**

2.Possibly card on a map restriction on the range of price(fiat)...

```
   **{6000...7000} ◁ rng price(fiat)**
```

But I am not sure that this is legal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think a function application is not what you need to get a subset of the price map, you want to restrict the map to the domain of Fiats, so let's use a domain restriction:

   ```
   fiat <: price
   ```

   That should yield {punto → 5500, panda → 6600}
2. Now we want a subset of that where the prices (the right side, i.e. the range) is restricted to 6000..7000:

   ```
   (fiat <: price) :> {6000,...,7000}
   ```

   That gives you the set of couples (Fiat,Price) where the prices are in the given interval.
3. Apply the cardinality operator to the result to get the number of found cars.

(Caveat: I'm not very familiar with VDM but the underlying logic should be quite the same in VDM, B, Z, etc. I did not check if the used syntax above is completely correct.)

**Edit:** I fixed the syntax of the interval, thanks to [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23951595/3604121).

Comment: Thank you for the help! I found out that you can also use set comprehension for this i.e. 
Using set construction:

{ c ∈fiat | 6000 <= price(c) and price(c) <= 7000}

Then take the cardinality of this set.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel's answer is very nearly correct, just missing curley brackets round the integer range at the end. Here is the example, tested under VDMJ:

```
values
    price = { <PUNTO> |-> 5500, <PANDA> |-> 6600, <MINI> |-> 9000 };

    BL = { <MINI> };

    fiat = { <PUNTO>, <PANDA> };
```

And then:

```
> p fiat <: price
= {<PUNTO> |-> 5500, <PANDA> |-> 6600}
Executed in 0.079 secs.
>
> p (fiat <: price) :> {6000,...,7000}
= {<PANDA> |-> 6600}
Executed in 0.023 secs.
>
> p card dom ((fiat <: price) :> {6000,...,7000})
= 1
Executed in 0.064 secs.
>
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you try to evaluate "price(fiat)" using this specification, VDMJ gives the following error:

> p price(fiat)
Error 3058: Map application argument is incompatible type
Map domain: (<MINI> | <PANDA> | <PUNTO>)
Argument: set of ((<PANDA> | <PUNTO>))